# Path integral - operator formalism and continuum limit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, path-integral, commutator, mathematics

Correlator of the position and momentum operators in quantum mechanics

$$\langle x_f, t_f|[\hat{x}(t), \hat{p}(t)]| x_i, t_i \rangle = i\hbar \langle x_f, t_f| x_i, t_i \rangle$$

since $[\hat{x}(t), \hat{p}(t)] = i\hbar$, where $t_i < t < t_f$. However in path integral formalism we get zero if we don't act carefully.

We get the correct result only by defining the velocity in momentum term carefully by not setting the $\delta t$ to zero limit hence with $\dot{x}=\lim_{\delta t \to 0}\frac{x(t+\delta t) - x(t)}{\delta t}$ term we are gonna get the correct result and inconsistencies will be gone.

My question is that how do we resolve this problem because in QFT I don't remember working on the discrete limit.

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): Consider for clarity to include proof of claim in 2nd paragraph.